# Angular : Map error: NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: angular

I am subscribing to an obserable to get data which works fine in angular 8. I need to format  the date when using mapping I get error saying

```
Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

So I believe adding the map operator and changed the return type. I am not sure whats wrong in the way that i have implemented the map. Could somebody let me know ?

```
export interface IPersonNote {
    id: number;
    personId: number;
    note: string;
    authorId: number;
    authorName: string;
    fileName: string;
    mimeType: string;
    alias: string;
    createdBy: string;
    createdDate: Date;
}
```

Original method

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
public personNotes: IPersonNote;

   loadPersonNotes() {
        this.isCurrentUser = this.id !== this.userService.getCurrentUser().id;
        this.userService.getPersonNote(this.id)
          .subscribe((x: IPersonNote) => {

            this.personNotes = x;
          });
      }
```

Modified method

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
public personNotes: IPersonNote;

loadPersonNotes() {
    this.isCurrentUser = this.id !== this.userService.getCurrentUser().id;
    this.userService.getPersonNote(this.id)
      .pipe(map(note => <any>{
        createdDate: format(note.createdDate, 'Do MMM YYYY'),
      }))
      .subscribe((x: IPersonNote) => {

        this.personNotes = x;
      });
  }
```

UI

```
<div *ngIf="personNotes">
<div class="portlet-body">
    <ul class="tier-history">
      <li *ngFor="let note of personNotes">
        <span class="tier-title"> {{ note.authorName }} </span>
        <span class="tier-dates">
            {{ note.created }} 
        </span>
        <span class="tier-title"> {{ note.note }} </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Service

```
public getPersonNote = (id: number): Observable<IPersonNote> =>
this.http.get<IPersonNote>(`${this.baseUrl}person-note/${id}`)
```

Comment: `IPersonNote` is just a struct, not iterable. Why your variable use plural `pesonNotes` while the type is singular `IPersonNote`?

Why do you want to do ngFor over a struct? It's just 1 instance of note.

Comment: `personNotes` is an object, not an array, therefore you are seeing the error...you need to use *ngFor on an array, not an object.

Comment: Nope. My existing method was returning more than one record and it was displaying correctly. Its only after the map that i am getting this error

Comment: declare personNotes as array ex: **`public personNotes: IPersonNote[];`** 
and in subscribe .. **`.subscribe((x: IPersonNote[]) => {`** . it will work

Comment: ok but how do i use the map to convert the date format. If you see my post in the modified code section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You method returns wrong data.

It should be like this (pay attention to the type of variable in `subscribe`):

```
   public personNotes: IPersonNote[]; // Not a single but few notes (or none)

   loadPersonNotes() {
        this.isCurrentUser = this.id !== this.userService.getCurrentUser().id;
        this.userService.getPersonNotesByUserId(this.id)
          .subscribe((personNotes: IPersonNote[]) => {

            this.personNotes = personNotes;
          });
   }
```

Comment: Considering that I have changed the type to array, how do i map to change the date format.

Comment: I am getting the error mentioned above when i am using the map for example  .pipe(map(note => <any>{
        createdDate: format(note[0].createdDate, 'Do MMM YYYY'),
      }))

Comment: I technically need to change every date field in the records to format in the map not just  the first one.

Comment: Also to prove that it works i commented out the map statement and removed the array notation and i am able to render all the records using ngFor

Comment: I have updated the post to include my service as well.

Comment: Mapping is a separate question.
It's hard to tell without seeing what is returned by `this.http.get<IPersonNote>(`person-note/${id}`)` but it's probably supposed to be `Òbservable<IPersonNote[]>` and not `Òbservable<IPersonNote>` as implied from yoru subscribe.

It worked because you probably were assigning an observable of a single object to the personNotes variable and for angular it's OK as obsravles are iterable. You need to understand what you want to store in `personNotes` and act accordingly in strongly typed manner.

So far it looks like it worked by coincidence

Comment: The requirement is to display the data. If an observable is iterable even as per my understanding, then why do we need to set the type to type []. Not convinced ? Could you tell me the scenario

Comment: I shall mark this answer anyways as it isnt wrong either

Comment: You don't have to but it helps to operate with correct types. Usually TypeScript would prevent you from assigning wrong type values - I don't know why you don;t get compilation errors while you should with `personNotes: IPersonNote` as far as I see. The idea is that http.get() should return an Observable of a single result whic can contain whatever you passed in JSON. Why and how it works in you case is hard to tell and outside of `in-comments` conversation. Sorry I can't help more with this.